# Grunt watch - swig doesn’t update .html

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, swig, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a small problem with configurating grunt. I use swig in my project, and when I run `grunt swig` grunt properly generate .html files, but when I use `grunt watch` task starts when I change anything in any .swig file, but it doesn’t update my .html files automaticly.

Here are most important parts of my Gruntfile.js:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = function ( grunt ) {

require( 'matchdep' ).filterDev( 'grunt-*' ).forEach( grunt.loadNpmTasks );

grunt.initConfig({
    swig: {
        development: ( function ( globals ) {
            return _.extend( globals, {
                init: { autoescape: true },
                dest: 'dev',
                src: [ 'dev/**/*.swig' ],
                generateSitemap: false,
                generateRobotstxt: false
            });
        })(require('./globals.json'))
    },

    useminPrepare: {
        html: [ 'dev/layouts/*.swig' ],
        options: {
            root: 'dev/',
            dest: 'build/'
        }
    },

    usemin: {
        html: [ 'build/*.html' ],
        options: {
            assetsDirs: [ 'build/assets/images', 'build' ],
            patterns: {
                css: [
                [/(images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the CSS to reference our revved images']
                ]
            }
        }
    }

    watch: {
        templates: {
            options: { nospawn: true },
            files: [ 'dev/**/*.swig' ],
            task: [ 'swig' ]
        }
    }

});

grunt.registerTask( 'default', [ 'watch' ] );

}
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: Hmmm you miss `s`. Its `tasks: [...]`. Here is the doc: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch
`tasks: ['jshint']`

Comment: Ouch.. yes, you have right. 
But even now grunt watch updates my html file only once. After making next changes in .swig file and save it I got info `Writing HTML to dev//index.html` but .html file doesn’t update.

Comment: If `grunt watch` compile the first time, then its work. Maybe the problem is in your initConfig. Its look different from example here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-swig